# How to open different windows based on command line arguments?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am trying to create simple WPF application for Windows. I need to show Window1 when get argument from command line and show Window2 without arguments. Also I need to pass this argument to Window1.

I create windows and define Application_Startup() method in App class:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Args.Length > 0)
    {
        // Here is I need to open Window1 and pass argument to this windows class
    }
    else
    {
        // Here is I need to open Window2
    }
}
```

1. How to open different windows based on argument?
2. How to pass argument from App class to window class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do it, but one way is to pass the data to the new window class via its constructor.

Like This:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Args.Length > 0)
    {
        var window1 = new Window1(e.Args[0]);
        window1.Show()
    }
    else
    {
         var window2 = new Window2();
         window2.Show()
    }
}
```